# NSScrollView inside another NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

I have a `NSScrollview` nested inside another `NSScrollview`. How do i make the inner view handle horizontal scrolling only? Vertical scrolling should move the outer view.

Currently i pass the `scrollWheel:` event to the outer view from the inner view, but it is very slow.

Comment: iPhone or MacOS?  I'm guessing MacOS since you're saying NSScrollView and not UIScrollView.

Answer (score 7):

I also had the problem of nested scroll views. The inner scroll view should scroll horizontally, and the outer should scroll vertically.

When handling scroll events from magic mouse / trackpad, it is important to pick only one of the scroll views for each gesture, otherwise you will see odd jerking when your fingers don't move perfectly straight. You should also ensure that tapping the trackpad with two fingers shows both scrollers.

When handling legacy scroll events from mighty mouse or mice with old fashioned scroll wheels, you must pick the right scroll view for each event, because there is no gesture phase information in the events.

This is my subclass for the inner scroll view, tested only in Mountain Lion:

```
@interface PGEHorizontalScrollView : NSScrollView {
    BOOL currentScrollIsHorizontal;
}
@end

@implementation PGEHorizontalScrollView
-(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    /* Ensure that both scrollbars are flashed when the user taps trackpad with two fingers */
    if (theEvent.phase==NSEventPhaseMayBegin) {
        [super scrollWheel:theEvent];
        [[self nextResponder] scrollWheel:theEvent];
        return;
    }
    /* Check the scroll direction only at the beginning of a gesture for modern scrolling devices */
    /* Check every event for legacy scrolling devices */
    if (theEvent.phase == NSEventPhaseBegan || (theEvent.phase==NSEventPhaseNone && theEvent.momentumPhase==NSEventPhaseNone)) {
        currentScrollIsHorizontal = fabs(theEvent.scrollingDeltaX) > fabs(theEvent.scrollingDeltaY);
    }
    if ( currentScrollIsHorizontal ) {
        [super scrollWheel:theEvent];
    } else {
        [[self nextResponder] scrollWheel:theEvent];
    }
}
@end
```

My implementation does not always forward Gesture cancel events correctly, but at least in 10.8 this does not cause problems.

Comment: This worked for me on 10.10, mostly. I needed to add `+(BOOL)isCompatibleWithResponsiveScrolling { return YES; }`, because NSScrollView detects overrides of `-scrollWheel:`, and I think there's a bug in the non-responsive scrolling.

Comment: I suspect the above scrollWheel method isn't doing what you think. On the 'began' phase you can never reach the isHorizontal check. Also, in that phase I always get 0,0 for the scroll deltas. Things actually work OK simply by _always_ calling super and then passing to the next responder anyway. Be aware that I think this causes issues with NSTrackingAreas if you are using them anywhere inside these scroll views.

Comment: @Giles Are you sure you aren't mixing up the `NSEventPhaseMayBegin` and the `NSEventPhaseBegan` phases? The "mayBegin" phase occurs when the user puts two fingers on the track pad. The "began" phase is when the user starts moving fingers, and at least one of `scrollingDeltaX` or `scrollingDeltaY` is non-zero at that point. Always calling super and next responder works okay for mice with traditional scroll wheels, but as far as I recall it causes issues with momentum scrolling (touch pad, magic mouse).

Comment: Anyway, I've been using this method since 2012, and no issues have ever been reported with it. I've used it on macOS 10.8 - 10.14, both with the trackpad and 3rd party mice. If there is an issue with it, I'd love to hear what version of macOS, and what input device you are using.

Comment: @JakobEgger My sincere apologies. I had made exactly the mistake you described - and more!. I wish I could down-vote my own comment! Thank you for responding with more detail. I was using the "deltaX" and not the "scrollingDeltaX" which give very different values over the lifecycle of the scroll. It has also fixed all the errors I was getting with NStrackingArea which was driving me mad - such a subtle issue. I was translating into Swift which is my terrible excuse...

Comment: @Giles I see you posted a swift translation -- very useful!

Answer (score 2):

This is my subclass of NSScrollView that does what you are asking.  Since it is merely passing the events it doesn't care about up the responder chain it should be as performant as if it weren't a subclass (or at least close)

h file

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface HorizontalScrollView : NSScrollView

@end
```

and m

```
@implementation HorizontalScrollView

- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"%@", theEvent);
    if(theEvent.deltaX !=0)
        [super scrollWheel:theEvent];
    else
        [[self nextResponder] scrollWheel:theEvent];

}
@end
```

Comment: This approach will cause subtle issues with NSTrackingAreas in your scroll views - this includes built in cursor effects on text-view links for example. Please see Jakob's answer and the comments below.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.

Answer is a translation of Jakob's excellent answer above, with the addition of a direction flag.

As mentioned in the comments on his answer, there can be subtle complications if this isn't done right. When simply forwarding all scrollWheel() calls to the next responder, I was seeing issues with NSTrackingAreas not being updated correctly and tooltips and cursor styles over NSTextView views being misaligned.

```
class ECGuidedScrollView: NSScrollView
{
    enum ScrollDirection {
        case vertical
        case horizontal
    }

    private var currentScrollMatches: Bool = false
    private var scrollDirection: ScrollDirection

    init(withDirection direction: ScrollDirection) {
        scrollDirection = direction
        super.init(frame: NSRect.zero)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent)
    {        
        // Ensure that both scrollbars are flashed when the user taps trackpad with two fingers
        if event.phase == .mayBegin {
            super.scrollWheel(with: event)
            nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: event)
            return
        }

        /*
         Check the scroll direction only at the beginning of a gesture for modern scrolling devices
         Check every event for legacy scrolling devices
         */

        if event.phase == .began || (event.phase == [] && event.momentumPhase == [])
        {
            switch scrollDirection {
            case .vertical:
                currentScrollMatches = fabs(event.scrollingDeltaY) > fabs(event.scrollingDeltaX)
            case .horizontal:
                currentScrollMatches = fabs(event.scrollingDeltaX) > fabs(event.scrollingDeltaY)
            }
        }

        if currentScrollMatches {
            super.scrollWheel(with: event)
        } else {
            self.nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The docs say NSEvent.Phase is an OptionSet, so you should be able to use `event.phase == []` instead of `event.phase.rawValue == 0`. Also, if you would make `scrollDirection` public and provide a default value, you wouldn't need an initialiser, and it would be easier to use in XIBs.

Comment: Thank you Jakob. I have corrected the OptionSet checking. I am not an IB user so I would rather enforced clarity in code, I leave your suggested changes there for others...