# Horizontal and vertical nested scroll views

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface, cocoa, nstableview

My view contains a horizontally scrolling Scroll View containing multiple vertically scrolling Table Views.

See diagram:

[image]

However, the Table Views are blocking horizontal scrolling in the Scroll View when the cursor is on them.

How can I allow the scroll to pass on to the superview?

---

Code for Application

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    var viewController: ViewController!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        viewController = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)  
        viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        window.contentView!.addSubview(viewController.view)
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

View Controller

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
    //...

    func addListView(listPath: String) {
        let listView = ListViewController(nibName: "ListView", bundle: nil)
        listView!.listPath = listPath

        listView!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.contentView.addSubview(listView!.view)
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

List View

```
class ListViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemsTitleView: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemsTableView: MyTableView!
    //...
}
```

TableView

```
class MyTableView: NSTableView {

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }

    var mainScrollView: NSScrollView? {
        let app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
        let delegate = app.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return delegate.viewController.scrollView
}

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        // do nothing
    }

    override func scrollWheel(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        if theEvent.scrollingDeltaY == 0 {
            // It's a horizontal scroll -> redirect it
            if let tableScrollView = enclosingScrollView, mainScrollView = mainScrollView {
                mainScrollView.scrollWheel(theEvent)
            }
        } else {
            // It's a vertical scroll -> behave normally
            super.scrollWheel(theEvent)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Will the table views ever need to scroll horizontally?

Comment: Hi Paul, no the table views will not ever scroll horizontally.

Comment: Oops my bad there are Custom Views around the inner Table Views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would try is to catch the scroll event as it's delivered to the table view. Once you've made sure the event object represents a horizontal-scroll gesture, redirect it to the main scroll view.

```
class MyTableView: NSTableView {

    var mainScrollView: NSScrollView? {
        // Your tables will need some way to access the main scroll view.
        // I'm assuming here that there's a reference to it on the AppDelegate
        let app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
        let delegate = app.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return delegate.mainScrollView
    }


    override func scrollWheel(theEvent: NSEvent) {

        if theEvent.scrollingDeltaY == 0 {
            // It's a horizontal scroll -> redirect it
            if let tableScrollView = enclosingScrollView, mainScrollView = self.mainScrollView {
                mainScrollView.scrollWheel(theEvent)
            }
        } else {
            // It's a vertical scroll -> behave normally
            super.scrollWheel(theEvent)
        }
    }
}
```

I have to say though, anytime you start messing with events like this, you need to be prepared for side-effects; in the simple demo-app I created to test this code, it seemed to work okay, but don't be surprised if this approach throws up additional challenges.

Comment: Thank you very much. Trackpad only here so will read along these lines toward a solution and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Now assuming that scrollWheel is a general function, in my case the scrollWheel function does not call, for example any 'print' statements added to it.

Comment: Yes, ``scrollWheel:`` is a general function, so it does work with a trackpad. My guess is that it's not getting called because you've made a simple mistake somewhere. You've made your tables instances of your subclass I assume? Is the signature of ``scrollWheel:`` exactly as it is in my code? What about if you override ``mouseDown:``, does that get ignored also?

Comment: My tables belong a custom view `NSViewController` which in turn belong to the main scroll view and the tables are declared  `@IBOutlet weak var itemsTableView: MyTableView!` The signature is exact `override func scrollWheel(theEvent: NSEvent) {...` and `override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {`

Comment: I'm no closer to understanding what the problem is from that description. The quickest way to sort this out is to post a sample project; if you take the trouble to do that, you're pretty much guaranteed to get a working answer. Otherwise you should post some code, and possibly screenshots of the xib/storyboard set-up.

Comment: Thanks for the project. Actually, you **haven't** made the ``itemsTableView`` tables subclasses of ``MyTableView`` - as it stands they're standard ``NSTableView``  instances. You need to go into your ``ListView.xib``, select the table view, then set the subclass value in the *Identity Inspector* to ``MyTableView``. Then, go to the ``ListView`` source file, delete the old ``itemsTableView`` outlet, and reconnect it. When you're done, that line should read: ``@IBOutlet weak var itemsTableView: MyTableView!``

Comment: I have been working on a similar project and the forwarding approach does throw up issues with NSTrackingArea. I have seen no other side effects though, so this approach seems OK if you don't want to use those.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul noted, there can be subtle issues with using his approach - I have seen problems with NSTrackingArea when using an approach very similar to his answer.

See Jakob's answer to a similar question for a more robust approach:

[NSScrollView inside another NSScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623785/nsscrollview-inside-another-nsscrollview/53848294#53848294)